# MySQL add to Columns with Group By doesn't show all rows

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT sender_userid,receiver_userid,message,message_read,`datetime`,sender_userid + receiver_userid AS message_token FROM messages
WHERE (receiver_userid='1000000172' OR sender_userid='1000000172') AND friendship_status=1 AND receiver_history=1
GROUP BY message_token;
```

The results are:
[image]

If I drop the Group By I get this result:

[image]

You will see in the second image there are 2 different 'message_token' results.

Why when I Group By this do I only get one result? Shouldn't it show both?

Is there a way to get both unique 'mesage_token' results?

Comment: Can you add CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to reproduce the problem?

Comment: better create a sqlfiddle url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research i found out that this is a bug for the following MySQL versions: **5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7**.
Here's the [bug report page](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70359) where the develelopers recognize it's now working as it should.

From the same page, the code to reproduce it:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT, b VARCHAR(1), INDEX(b,a)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2,'s'),(5,'h'),(3,'q'),(1,'a'),(3,'v'),
(6,'u'),(7,'s'),(5,'y'),(1,'z'),(5,'i'),(2,'y');

SELECT b, max(a) FROM t1 WHERE b = 'i' OR a = 2 GROUP BY b;
```